# System freezes when using an Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, usb, 22.04, ethernet

I need help with an issue I've been experiencing. After one of the updates for Ubuntu 22.04, whenever I connect my laptop to an Ethernet cable, all programs and the graphical environment start to hang. For the first minute after connecting the cable, I can check the connection speed using `speedtest`, but then everything freezes. When the cable is disconnected and only Wi-Fi is used, everything works perfectly. I tried connecting the cable to another laptop (Windows), and it works fine there. Here are my system details:

- Kernel version 6.2.0-37 (I've tried 36 and 39, but the problem persists);
- Ubuntu Unity 7.6.0
- Compiz 0.9.14.1
- The cable is connected via an Ethernet-to-USB adapter, as my laptop doesn't have an Ethernet port (I've tried other USB ports, but the problem remains the same).

Comment: Watch the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the adapter. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: @waltinator Dear sir, thank you for your help! There was nothing unusual in the logs. Essentially, the internet itself works, but after a short time, all programs from the terminal to the browser freeze. (Only when Ethernet is connected.) Even rebooting the system doesn't work! But here's what helped me: boot in Safe Mode → Enable networking → Repair broken packages. Now everything works fine! Thank you for your time.